# react-google-maps Marker Click Event

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am using the stock code for the clustered map posted on the `react-google-maps` documentation. I am trying to extend the code by adding a click event for the marker that will take the marker URL from the API and then call `window.location` to change the page.

Here is an example of one of the markers that is returned from my API:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Oxford",
  slug: "oxford",
  lat: 51.752021,
  lng: -1.257726,
}
```

I have added an event `onMarkerClick` to the marker and the method is getting called properly. I hardcoded window.location and it gets called, I just don't know how to get the slug value.

I am assuming that I have to store the slug value differently from how I am doing it in the example below. I am new to React so I am probably missing something really obvious

```
import React from 'react'

const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");
const { compose, withProps, withHandlers } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { MarkerClusterer } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer");

const MapWithAMarkerClusterer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCvakAjEUpqfnucJu-CoClBD1CtTKZUGxQ&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 56px)' }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 56px)' }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 56px)' }} />,
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onMarkerClustererClick: () => (markerClusterer) => {
      console.log('Clicked a cluster')
    },
    onMarkerClick: () => (marker) => {
      // link to post view page
      //
      //
      //
      //
      //
      console.log('Go to the marker post page')
      window.location = '/post/oxford';
    }
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 12.2637937, lng: 75.947508 }}
  >
    <MarkerClusterer
      onClick={props.onMarkerClustererClick}
      averageCenter
      enableRetinaIcons
      gridSize={60}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
          key={marker.id}
          position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
          slug={marker.slug}
        />
      ))}
    </MarkerClusterer>
  </GoogleMap>
);

class TestMap extends React.PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ markers: [] })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = '/api/posts';
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ markers: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapWithAMarkerClusterer markers={this.state.markers} />
    )
  }
}

export default TestMap
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom component for the Marker and identify it by an additional parameter - for example, an `id`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Marker} from 'react-google-maps';

const CustomMarker = (props) => {
    const {id} = props;

    const onMarkerClick = (evt) => {
        console.log(id);
    };

    return (
        <Marker
            onClick={onMarkerClick}
            {...props}
        />
    );
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

Answer (score 6):

In this example

```
<Marker
      onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
      key={marker.id}
      position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
      slug={marker.slug}
/>

onMarkerClick: () => (marker) => {  //<- event object, not a marker object!  
   //.. 
}
```

a specific Google Maps `event` object is getting passed into `onMarkerClick` event handler instead of `marker` object.

You could utilize [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass the `marker` object as a parameter like this:

```
<Marker
      key={marker.photo_id}
      position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
      onClick={props.onMarkerClick.bind(this,marker)}
/>
```

And then given the structure of `marker` object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Oxford",
  slug: "oxford",
  lat: 51.752021,
  lng: -1.257726,
}
```

`onMarkerClick` event could be initialized like this:

```
onMarkerClick: () => (marker) => {
  window.location = '/post/' + marker.slug;
}
```